# Why SQLite Primary Key column auto incrementing is not working?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using SQLite3 in my Android app and I was having a hard time trying to query records I had already insert.

After much debugging, I found out that the problem was that the `SQLite` auto increment was NOT working.

The problem is that SQLite3 treats

```
"CREATE TABLE test_table (
id **INT** PRIMARY KEY,
name text)";
```

differently from

```
"CREATE TABLE test_table (
id **INTEGER** PRIMARY KEY,
name text)";
```

Using `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` works fine to create an auto increment column, whereas 
using INT PRIMARY KEY will simple NOT work.

Thanks this author  where I found this info.
http://mydumbthoughts.wordpress.com/2010/06/12/sqlite-primary-key-column-not-auto-incrementing/

Comment: That's a question with an answer I already found. Just sharing something that might same others some time :)

Comment: augh, the link has rotted :(